# pyqt4 how to import and change custom font for painted text

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I draw a text and question is how to import custom font (tff file in the same folder as script file) and change font.
here is the code:

```
def paintEvent(self, e):
    painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
    painter.setRenderHint(painter.Antialiasing)

    self.drawText(e, painter)

    super(SpeedPrg, self).paintEvent(e)

def drawText(self, event, qp):

    qp.setPen(QtGui.QColor(255,255,255))
    qp.drawText(event.rect(), QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, str(self.setText))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use code like this:

```
# Load the font: 
font_db = QFontDatabase()
font_id = font_db.addApplicationFont("your_font.ttf")
# families = font_db.applicationFontFamilies(font_id)
your_ttf_font = QFont("one of your font families")

# tell painter to use your font: 
qp.setFont(your_ttf_font)
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with this on MacOS (10.13.6) but not on Linux.   The Mac doesn't seem to find the font that is located in the same folder as the script and loads a default font instead, without complaint.  On linux with the same file/folder structure, it loads the requested font.

Comment: how to know if it finds the font we looking for?